# Should be simple, array based on user input with a loop

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, user-input

I need to have a spreadsheet that prompts the user to input the following:

- Amount of times they've tested
- starting voltage
- number of resistors in the circuit
- distance between the resistors
- resistance of each resistor

I need to output the following:

- equivalent resistance
- current theoretical
- voltage at each stop string
- response based on input values

I've managed to get the user input to work. I believe my issue is setting up an array in the loop so I can take the sum of all the data for things like equivalent resistance.

I need a way to perform functions such as summing certain group of input values after they've been logged. I think that's an array, but I'm still teaching myself VBA. Any help is appreciated!

```
    Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

TrialRuns = InputBox("How many separate voltage sources have you tested?")

Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To TrialRuns

TrialName = InputBox("Please input the name or some other type of identifying quality (ie. Level 1 load side)")
Rows("2").Insert Shift:=x1ShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=x1FormatFromRightorBelow
StartingVoltage = "What is the starting voltage?"
Msg = "How many resistors/loads do you have?"
VoltageInput = InputBox(StartingVoltage)

ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = TrialName
ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = VoltageInput
QtyEntry = InputBox(Msg)
ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = QtyEntry


Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Range("C2").Value

    Rows("3").Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
ResistanceValue = InputBox("Hey dude, what is the resistance value in ohms?")
RunLength = InputBox("Cool! How far is it (in feet) from the previous load? Use distance from voltage source if this is the first load.")

ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Value = RunLength
ActiveSheet.Range("D3").Value = ResistanceValue
ActiveSheet.Range("E3").Value = 1 / ResistanceValue

Next i

Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: If you are learning VBA, I would highly recommend using `Option Explicit`. You are using all sorts of undeclared variables. Also, please try to indent the code consistently. What you have posted is quite hard to read.

Comment: A loop which uses a series of input boxes to load the values into a spreadsheet is annoying to most users (an annoyance that is unlikely to be lessened by the repeated "hey dude"). Why not just have the user directly enter the values into the spreadsheet and then have the VBA code read them (perhaps after the user selects the values to be processed)?

Comment: Hi John, how would I go about having the VBA code read them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand what you're looking for but you should be able to get the sum of each group without the use of arrays.

In this block of code add the following:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim runTotal As Double
Dim resistTotal As Double

runTotal = 0
resistTotal = 0

For i = 1 To Range("C2").Value

    Rows("3").Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
    ResistanceValue = InputBox("Hey dude, what is the resistance value in    ohms?")
    RunLength = InputBox("Cool! How far is it (in feet) from the previous     load? Use distance from voltage source if this is the first load.")

    ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Value = RunLength
    ActiveSheet.Range("D3").Value = ResistanceValue
    ActiveSheet.Range("E3").Value = 1 / ResistanceValue

    runTotal = runTotal + RunLength
    resistTotal = resistTotal + ResistanceValue

    If i = Range("C2").Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("G4").Value = runTotal
        ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value = runTotal
    End If

Next i
```

If this doesn't solve your problem and you want to use arrays you could add something similar to the following:

```
Dim runArr() As Double
ReDim runArr(1 To QtyEntry)

For i = 1 To Range("C2").Value
    '...
    runArr(i) = RunLength
Next i
```